# Query to find players with same ip

Tags: mysql

Im new in mysql so i need some help to make a query 
i have db : playerTracker
with tables : player time and ip

I need a query to show me only differed players name that have the same ip. sorted by time. last one first ( time is this format : 2013-06-03 23:02:47 )

Comment: how are the columns defined?

Comment: You should add sample data, and sample output in your question, it would be even better to create a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: This is pretty simple. There are millions of web pages that will demonstrate how to perform a `SELECT` statement in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could write something out as followed:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    your_table
WHERE   your_col=some_condition
    ORDER BY ip, time DESC;
```

or

```
    SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    your_table  
    ORDER BY ip, time DESC;
```

The multi-order here would allow you to view players that had the same ip

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY ip
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6

Comment: Fixed the error most likely, also look into the `group by` clause which is related and will also help you solve your query

Comment: @user2546981 Also note dianuj's clarification on how to use the where clause for your query

Comment: the last one works... somewhat . but i need to only show a player only once sorted by time. if a players logs out and back in.my plugin makes a new record for that time :) if i run that quary and a player loged in and out 100 times it shows me that player 100 times

Comment: @user2546981 That is where you will have read up on `group by` to figure it out. How else will you learn how to do it without us next time? Also joining your table on itself might also work, but its up to you now.

Comment: its not about sort by. its removing duplicate name in results

Comment: also the orber by shows ip even if its not duplicated... meh. il just quit. fu*k it